# Specifying return type in a angular2 typescript method

Tags: typescript, angular, ecmascript-6

I have a data access method in which I use map in order to transform a hash into an array so i can iterate over them in my view:

```
public getCrawlsStatuses():Observable<ICrawlsStatus[]> {

        let _statusesURL:string = `${this.API_URL}/crawl_statuses`;

        return this._http.get(_statusesURL)
            .map((res:Response) => {
                let statuses:ICrawlsStatus[] = [];
                Object.keys(res.json()).map(key => {
                    statuses.push({
                        name: key,
                        total: res.json()[key]
                    })
                });
                return statuses;
            })
            .catch(CrawlsService.onError);
    }
```

However I find the variable statuses a little redundant, so decided to shorten the mapping by simply utilising the return of the observable's map method:

```
public getCrawlsStatuses():Observable<ICrawlsStatus[]> {

        let _statusesURL:string = `${this.API_URL}/crawl_statuses`;

        return this._http.get(_statusesURL)
            .map((res:Response) => {
                return Object.keys(res.json()).map(key => {
                    return {
                        name: key,
                        total: res.json()[key]
                    }
                });
            })
            .catch(CrawlsService.onError);
    }
```

This in terms of type checking works ok for components outside of here, as they need to expect `crawlsStatuses: ICrawlsStatus[];` but for the life of me I can't find a way to make the returned object to have a type internally to, something like:

```
return <ICrawlsStatus>{
  name: key,
  total: res.json()[key]
}
```

I would like to get an error if the returned keys do not match the my interface. e.g. names, totally....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But for the life of me I can't find a way to make the returned object to have a type internally to, something like

Just create a local variable:

```
const result: ICrawlsStatus = {
  name: key,
  total: res.json()[key]
}
return result;
```

## More

You should avoid type assertion as much as you can : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html

Comment: That's interesting but in this case, result would be more or less a redundant variable similar to my array method. I was hoping for more of a 1 liner that would return a ICrawlsStatus type. is that not possible?

Comment: Also regarding type assertion, would you have not tried to include a type here if it was you doing it?